# MQ messages disappeared

Tags: java, websphere, message-queue, ibm-mq

I was able to browse the messages in the queues of a particular Queue Manager. At that time my listener ports down to process the messages. So I turned my listener ports to UP and restarted the servers. Now, I can not find any of the messages.

What is the reason for this problem? Please help.

Thanks :))

Comment: some code otherwise it will be too difficult to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities here.  The first as Yeradis has noted is that the messages expired.  You can verify this simply enough while browsing the messages.  Look at the expiry field.

The other possibility is that your listener is consuming the messages and then either discarding them or requeuing them.  It is not uncommon to find a listener that consumes messages and then, either because they did not match a selector or failed some other validation immediately and silently discards them.  It is difficult to diagnose this short of running a trace.  If you have the [MO71 SupportPac](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO71) installed, you can look at the queue stats in real time to see how many GET operations were executed against the queue.

Messages can be requeued if the listener backs the message out until the backout count threshold is exceeded and then moves the message to an exception queue or to the DLQ. In this case the messages will be found in one of these queues.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is not an expiration time on your messages or your queue.